# Selectpicker - selected option is not shown in the button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using the Selectpicker plugin in my current web project. I am also using Codeigniter 4 as a web framework.

**Explanation of the situation:**
I first load the select options for the select field from a database. Then an Ajax request is executed by a button click. The resulting json response contains the value(s) to be selected for the select options.

**Problem:**
The select options are selected appropriately according to the value in the json response (there is a tick next to the options), but they are not displayed in the button, so the title of the button is not updated.

**Example:**
For the field "staff_number" the options "1234" and "5678" are loaded from the database. After clicking on a button, an Ajax request is executed and the result for the field "staff_number" is "1234". This option is then selected in the select field. So when you click on it, there is a tick next to the option (see picture 1). This option appears, but not in the title of the button, as it still says "Please select" (see picture 2).

**Picture 1:**
[select option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnogj.png)

**Picture 2:**
[empty button title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgj5F.png)

My current code of the view looks like this:

```
<label for="staff_number">Staff number:*</label><br>
<select class="selectpicker" id="staff_number" multiple name="staff_number[]" title="Please select">
<?php foreach($staff_numbers as $each):?>
<option value="<?=$each?>" <?php echo set_select('staff_number',$each, ( !empty($data) && $data == $each ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>> <?=$each?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

My Current Ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'getInformation.php',
type: 'POST',
data: {field : 'id', value: id.substring(4)},
success: function(data) {
//JSON needs to be parsed to be accessible in JS
var json = JSON.parse(data);
                            
//Asign values to input fields
var staff_number= json['staff_number'];
$.each(staff_number.split(","), function(i,e){
$("#staff_number option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);                            
});
//$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
//$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');

});
```

I would appreciate any suggestions. :)

Best regards
schwaluck

Answer (score 0):

You firstly need to deselect all selected option and you need to refresh the selectpicker after making selection as below:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'getInformation.php',
type: 'POST',
data: {field : 'id', value: id.substring(4)},
success: function(data) {
//JSON needs to be parsed to be accessible in JS
var json = JSON.parse(data);
                            
//deselect all option first
 $("#staff_number option:selected").removeAttr("selected");

//Asign values to input fields
var staff_number= json['staff_number'];
$.each(staff_number.split(","), function(i,e){
    $("#staff_number option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);                            
});
//$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the approach. However, the problem still exists. Note: I have adjusted my post again (added two pictures).